# Euler project Prob 23 Non abundant sums :python2

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to solve problem 23 in project euler in python2. I am getting the result as 4179935 but the correct answer is 4179871

This is the actual question
A perfect number is a number for which the sum of its proper divisors is exactly equal to the number. For example,
the sum of the proper divisors of 28 would be 1 + 2 + 4 + 7 + 14 = 28, which means that 28 is a perfect number.

A number n is called deficient if the sum of its proper divisors is less than n and it is called abundant if this sum exceeds n.

As 12 is the smallest abundant number, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 6 = 16, the smallest number that can be written as the sum of
two abundant numbers is 24. By mathematical analysis, it can be shown that all integers greater than 28123 can be
written as the sum of two abundant numbers. However, this upper limit cannot be reduced any further by analysis
even though it is known that the greatest number that cannot be expressed as the sum of two abundant numbers is less than this limit.

Find the sum of all the positive integers which cannot be written as the sum of two abundant numbers.

```py
import itertools


def find_non_abundant_sums(num):
    non_abundant_number = set()
    non_abundant_sums = set()
    all_numbers = set(range(1,num+1))
    for i in range(1,num+1):
        divisor_sum = find_divisor_sum(i)
        if(divisor_sum > i):
            non_abundant_number.add(i)
    for j in itertools.combinations(non_abundant_number,2):
        if(j[0]+j[1] < num+1):
            non_abundant_sums.add(j[0]+j[1])
    print (sorted(non_abundant_sums))
    return sum(all_numbers-non_abundant_sums)

def find_divisor_sum(num):
    divisors = set()
    for i in range(1,num):
        if(num%i==0):
            divisors.add(i)
    return sum(divisors)

print (find_non_abundant_sums(28123))
```

expected: 4179871
actual: 4179935